# Declare a variable of a table type in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I need to write a stored procudere like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS TABLE(user_id integer, count bigint) AS $$
    some_array integer[];
    ret_val __WHAT_TYPE_;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(some_array, 1)
    LOOP
        //modify the ret_val
    END LOOP;
    RETURN ret_val;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I don't know what type of `ret_val` I should declare?

Comment: I think you need to declare it as `record`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a function returning a table you do not need a variable for returned value. 
The columns of the table are treated as OUT parameters.
You can assign values to them and use RETURN NEXT, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() 
RETURNS TABLE(user_id integer, counts bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
    i integer;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..4
    LOOP
        user_id = i;
        counts = i* i;
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM foo();

 user_id | counts 
---------+--------
       1 |      1
       2 |      4
       3 |      9
       4 |     16
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks much. But could'nt you explain what OUT parameters are in a nutshell? I just haven't come across with that term before...

Comment: Read about OUT parameters [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/129-Use-of-OUT-and-INOUT-Parameters.html)